# Outlook: How to prove that the sender modified the email timestamp?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have the need of checking whether a person faked an email to pretend he sent it to me, which can cover up his dereliction of duty and show he is innocent.

Let's say on July 25, I sent an email regarding a request to him.

Now it is September 30, I sent an email to ask him why he didn't reply for so long.

He: Oh I replied after a few days you sent to me. Didn't you receive it? See. (He resent me the "proof" email showing the time is July 27.)

I checked the entire mail box including the junk and trash bin, but no, the last email sent from him is on March 19, 2019. Dramatically, blaming him for not replying email turns out to be him blaming me not receiving email.

Additional information: This person has the history of ignoring my email(at that time I have the evidence to debunk him). What a shame.

From the receiver side, it is really hard to tell whether the date was modified by the sender, isn't it? It is quite easy to change the send date while maintaining the general "Re: " content. Using the "view source" option doesn't help.

Is there any approach to track? The proof is on the intermediate server and of course can't access it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that email sent on certain date of outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/655812/how-to-prove-that-email-sent-on-certain-date-of-outlook)

Comment: How about this issue?

Comment: You appear to be trying to prove a negative.   Assuming he just forwarded "the earlier" email on to you, it is not possible to disprove when it was sent by looking at your copy of the email.  You would need to get access to the mail server log, or (and with a witness if neccessary) go to his computer to look at the outbox.

Answer (score 0):

Did you receive the message now in your Outlook?
If yes, you could check its message header and analyze it in https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/o365, you could check the actual time when it was transferred in Mail server.

If not, you may need to use message tracking log to check if it arrived your Exchange server ( if you are in Exchange server).